# Azure Python SDK Issue - Extracting endpoint information from RoleInstance

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to access RoleInstance endpoint information of the Azure RoleInstance using Azure Python SDK. However RoleInstance does not have any attributes to find endpoint info.

Attributes for RoleInstance are as follows:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'fqdn', 'instance_error_code', 'instance_fault_domain', 'instance_name', 'instance_size', 'instance_state_details', 'instance_status', 'instance_upgrade_domain', 'ip_address', 'power_state', 'role_name']
```

I have a sample code that looks like following:

```
deployment = self.sms.get_deployment_by_slot(hosted_service.service_name, 'production')

for instance in deployment.role_instance_list:
    print('Instance name: ' + instance.instance_name)
    print('Instance status: ' + instance.instance_status)
    print('Instance size: ' + instance.instance_size)
    print('Instance role name: ' + instance.role_name)
    print('Instance ip address: ' + instance.ip_address)
    print('')
```

How can I extract endpoint information from 'instance'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this.  We've filed and issue, and just now checked in a fix for it.

[Missing role instance endpoint in get_deployment_by_X](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/131)

Have a look at the pull request referenced in the issue, you should be able to patch your library pretty easily, or pip install from our github repository.

Here's the code you would use to access the first endpoint:

```
endpoint = instance.instance_endpoints[0]
print(endpoint.name)
print(endpoint.protocol)
print(endpoint.public_port)
print(endpoint.local_port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for SDK here: [https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/servicemanagement/**init**.py](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/servicemanagement/__init__.py), I see `Deployment` has a property called `input_endpoint_list`.

```
deployment = self.sms.get_deployment_by_slot(hosted_service.service_name, 'production')
for input_endpoint in deployment.input_endpoint_list:
    print ('Role Name:' + input_endpoint.role_name)
    print ('Role VIP:' + input_endpoint.vip)
    print ('Port:' + input_endpoint.port)
```

Will this work?

Comment: Yes, Deployment has a property of 'input_endpoint_list' but it does not fetch RoleInstance endpoint info